# Android Directories

Tags: android, facebook

I have recently rooted my android Smartphone because I wanted to know when I logged into my Facebook account using the Facebook app I saved my login credentials by clicking on save login info. Now I wanted to know where the password/login credentials get saved in which of the android directories & where apps usually store account login information locally on the mobile phone.

Comment: I think your title doesn't correspond well with your question, at least it could be something like "Android Apps' directories" because each App has its own and separated from others.

Comment: Next time I will be careful! :)

Comment: Why would it store password/login credentials. That makes no sense.

Comment: So you do not have to again input the password if you re-login on the same device once you logged out!

Comment: The app doesn't need to store the username and password for that. It just need something to prove that you logged in before. For the same reason you don't store passwords in cleartext on servers you shouldn't do it on the client and I highly doubt Facebook does it.

Comment: On servers, they are encrypted! It is quite possible that the app uses some other methods that this device has logged in earlier!

Comment: @captainanas - passwords are not encrypted; they're *hashed*. Aside from that: this question is off-topic: it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app stores its data in its own directory, which you will find (if rooted) with a good file manager (e.g. Total Commander) under:

```
/data/data/<package-name>/
```

E.g. for Total Commander this would be:

```
/data/data/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander
```

(for Facebook app I don't know).

Mostly the apps store their data in sqlite databases, so you would need an app to read these databases.
I used SQLite Editor on my rooted phone, but there are others too.
With that you have to search through the tables till you find your data.
Most likely the passwords are saved as hashes, not in clear text.
You would need rainbow tables to get back to the plain text, with little chances only, depends on the complexity of the password.

Browsers will let you read saved passwords, here you don't even need root but this is likely not what your want to know ;)

So to be short: I don't know where Facebook app saves credentials, I would try to search the Facebook directory with sqlite app.